# 100% height container with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create a container, which is spanned 100% horizontally in browser, but - and that's a problem - with fixed horizontal scrollbar displayed regardless of how wide contents are. Think of Microsoft Azure Portal (if you know, how it works).

Currently I'm using the following SCSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.editor-container {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.editor-item {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;

    .panel {
        height: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

Site contains Bootstrap's nav on top and contents below:

```
<body>    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    (...)
    </nav>

    <div class="editor-container">
        <div class="editor-item">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Heading
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-item"></div>
        <div class="editor-item"></div>
    </div>
```

My problem is, that though the container indeed spans 100% vertically, horizontal scrollbar is pushed out of page and vertical scrollbar appears.

[image: Scrollbar pushed out from screen]

How can I make sure, that horizontal scrollbar is displayed on the bottom and no vertical one is present?

Comment: that's possible, but using Bootstrap will rather make it more complicated...

Comment: @Johannes That's possible how exactly?